# Is it a bad idea to use the new Dynamic Keyword as a replacement switch statement?

Tags: c#-4.0

I like the new Dynamic keyword and read that it can be used as a replacement visitor pattern.

It makes the code more declarative which I prefer.

Is it a good idea though to replace all instances of switch on 'Type' with a class that implements dynamic dispatch.

```
class VistorTest
{
    public string DynamicVisit(dynamic obj)
    {
        return Visit(obj);
    }


    private string Visit(string str)
    {
        return "a string was called with value " + str;
    }


    private string Visit(int value)
    {
        return "an int was called with value " + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from overloading... aside from being confusing.

Comment: @Dykam, what more would you like to know?

Comment: What are you achieving here that could not be achieved with generics?

Comment: @klausbyskov: The visitor pattern is tricky to get right.  Generics don't work (necessarily) for this.  Here's a "classic" implementation for C#: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/c%2523

Comment: This is for dynamic dispatching, which isn't possible via generics without reverting to runtime code compilation or reflection.

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers, meant I needed to add more chars to my comment. It was my initial response. But the answer by Reed fairly well respresents my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really depends on what you consider a "good idea".

This works, and it works in a fairly elegant manner.  It has some advantages and some disadvantages to other approaches.

On the advantage side:

1. It's concise, and easy to extend
2. The code is fairly simple

For the disadvantages:

1. Error checking is potentially more difficult than a classic visitor implementation, since all error checking must be done at runtime.  For example, if you pass `visitorTest.DynamicVisit(4.2);`, you'll get an exception at runtime, but no compile time complaints.
2. The code may be less obvious, and have a higher maintenance cost.

Personally, I think this is a reasonable approach.  The visitor pattern, in a classic implementation, has a fairly high maintenance cost and is often difficult to test cleanly.  This potentially makes the cost slightly higher, but makes the implementation much simpler.

With good error checking, I don't have a problem with using dynamic as an approach here.  Personally, I'd probably use an approach like this, since the alternatives that perform in a reasonable manner get pretty nasty otherwise.

However, there are a couple of changes I would make here.  First, as I mentioned, you really need to include error checking.

Second, I would actually make `DynamicVisit` take a `dynamic` directly, which might make it  (slightly) more obvious what's happening:

```
class VistorTest
{
    public string DynamicVisit(dynamic obj)
    {
        try
        {
            return Visit(obj);
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException e)
        {
            // Handle the exception here!
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid type specified");
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

     // ...Rest of code
```

Comment: Do you know of any overheads with using this though, I read that doing dynamic dispatch is more expensive in some languages, is that the case here? I love it and would like to use it liberally sprinkling it all over my code like sugar, but I just need to make sure that I have read what I have correctly :)

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: The dynamic dispatch using dynamic is actually fairly highly optimized.  This is likely as good of an approach as you can get in C# that remains flexible. Otherwise, the best (flexible) option  I know of is the delegate approach Judith Bishop came up with...

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: I actually implemented a double dispatching option based on code generation at one point - but Dynamic does this same thing, and is MUCH easier.  I'd profile, but I suspect you'll be quite happy with the perf doing it this way...

Answer (score 2):

The visitor pattern exists primarily to work around the fact that some languages do not allow [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) and [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch).

> Multiple dispatch or multimethods is the feature of some object-oriented programming languages in which a function or method can be dynamically dispatched based on the run time (dynamic) type of more than one of its arguments. This is an extension of single dispatch polymorphism where a method call is dynamically dispatched based on the actual derived type of the object. Multiple dispatch generalizes the dynamic dispatching to work with a combination of two or more objects.

Until version 4, C# was one of those languages. With the introduction of the `dynamic` keyword, however, C# allows developers to opt-in to this dispatch mechanism just as you've shown. I don't see anything wrong with using it in this manner.

You haven't changed the type safety at all, because even a `switch` (or more likely dispatch dictionary, given that C# does not allow switching on type) would have to have a `default` case that throws when it can't match a function to call, and this will do exactly the same if it can't find a suitable function to bind to.